# How to disable endpoint based on environment in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a controller comprising of a bunch of swagger endpoints. For one of the endpoint I want it to be disabled / hidden for PROD env, and the rest of them to be active for all envs. How could i get that done ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Filter.

```java
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getRequestURI().contains("secret") && env.getProperty("environment").equals("Production"))
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Unauthorized!");
        else
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```